# Use Python sshtunnel for port-forwarding rest request

Tags: python, networking, ssh, portforwarding

At my company we currently have a REST API that can only be accessed by a particular jump box.

I would like to ssh to this box, from the server my Python code is running on, to make rest calls.

I've written this code below, but it's hanging and not doing anything when I run it:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import requests

remote_user = 'me'
remote_host = 'jump.box.net'
remote_port = 22
local_host = '10.30.22.218'
local_port = 443

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
   (remote_host, remote_port),
   ssh_username=remote_user,
   ssh_private_key_password='mypassword',
   ssh_private_key='~/.ssh/mykey',
   remote_bind_address=(local_host, local_port),
   )

server.start()

r = requests.get(url = 'https://ourinternalendpoint.com/api/stuff',verify=False).content
print(r)
server.stop()
```

The local host IP is actually the IP of the ourinternalendpoint domain.

What am I doing wrong? I know that the remote_host name is correct, as is the port, the user, the private key and password for ssh-ing.

The server.start() command also completes.  It is hanging on the get request.

I'm doing this from a Linux server, I'm open to using Bash for port forwarding for my Python script if need be.

Comment: Hi George, it's hanging on _server.start()_? Have you tried to use ssh manually to check that everything is alright? SSH on your machine it's acessible only by root?

Comment: ssh from the command line works fine.  That’s a good point, I’ll find the exact line it hangs on tomorrow!

Comment: Sure! Since you discover it, post here.

Comment: It hangs on the get request, I've updated the post.

Answer (score 9):

I managed to fix this!  The main changes were to the code:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import requests
import paramiko

pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(private_key_path, password=private_key_password)

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (remote_host, ssh_port),
    ssh_username=remote_user,
    ssh_private_key=pkey,
    remote_bind_address=('internal_url.com', 443),
    local_bind_address=('localhost', 1478)
)

server.start()
try:
    r = requests.get(url = 'https://internal_url:1478/some/endpoint',verify=False)
finally:
    server.stop()`
```

I also had to add a mapping to /etc/hosts:, I had to add in a line like this:

```
127.0.0.1 internal_url
```